# How do you dump just the create database statement using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

How do you dump just the create database statement using mysqldump? I am working with a database
with hundreds of tables, most of which can be ignored. I cannot find the correct options for mysqldump
that let you dump just the database create statement without processing all the tables or using
the --ignore-table switch. I guess I could grep out just the create database statement in the output
but it still means processing all the tables. Seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: If there's no option specifically for this, you could always kludge it with `--where 1 = 2`, since this won't select any rows in the dump.

Comment: I usually just execute `show create table tablename` and copy the output from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, since you can't use [mysqldump](/questions/tagged/mysqldump) for it, use the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) client in the command line as follows:

```
mysql -uroot -p -e 'SHOW CREATE DATABASE databasename\G' | grep 'Create Database' | sed -e 's/^Create Database: \(.*\)$/\1/'
```

Comment: Then, would you please mark this answer as the correct one? (So I can get the reputation reward).